# Como usar multiple select no form PHP para fazer consulta no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, query, select, formulário

tenho uma busca com um select que pode selecionar mais de uma opção, mas não sei como fazer para que eles busque todas as opções selecionadas.

Atualmente ele faz a busca, insere os valores na url (estou usando `GET`), mas não consegue fazer o `SELECT` de todos os valores. Abaixo o trecho do código:

```
<form method="get">
<select name="bairro">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>
</form>
```

e a consulta:

```
$bairro = $_GET['bairro'];
$query=("SELECT * FROM terrenos WHERE bairro = '".$bairro."'"};
```

Se eu seleciono A e B por exemplo, a URL fica `&bairro=A&bairro=B`, mas daí o `$_GET` só pega 1 bairro, como faço para usar todos para retornar para a consulta?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere o `name` do `select` desse jeito:

```
<input ... name="bairro[]" ... >
```

Dessa forma você irá receber o `$_GET["bairro"]` como sendo uma array com os dados do `form`.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro ponto, é que um `select` com múltiplas opções, sempre enviará um `array`. Então, você deve tratar ele como tal. Entretanto, o name deve ser tratado como um array (`name="bairro[]"`).

```
<form method="get">    
    <select name="bairro[]">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>    
</form>
```

O segundo ponto, é que a sua consulta é vulnerável a **SQL injection**. Por isso, o exemplo será utilizando `PDO`.

Segundo o seu exemplo, consultando utilizando o operador `=` e não `like`, o jeito mais fácil de consultar múltiplos registros, é utilizando o operador `IN`

Para ser seguro, você deve utilizar *prepard statements*. Entretanto, PDO não possui suporte a consulta `IN` via `prepared statements`.

Para resolver isso, você terá que criar a string de SQL conforme a quantidade de parâmetros:

```
$paramtersQty = count($_GET['bairro']); //Retorna a quantidade de parâmetros
$markedPlaceholders = array_fill(0 , $paramtersQty , '?'); //Cria um array com placeholders para a query
$markedPlaceholders = implode(',' , $markedPlaceholders); //transforma os placeholders em uma única string.

//cria o statement
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM terrenos WHERE bairro ('.$markedPlaceholders.');');

//passa todos os argumentos como parâmetros para a consulta.
$statement->execute($_GET['bairro']);
```

Feito isso, você terá uma consulta utilizando múltiplos parâmetros vindos de um único `select`.